# Quantum circuit runtime

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, simulation, qiskit-runtime

I want to estimate the execution time of some experiments, and I would be interested to know how the time needed to run a quantum circuit grows in function of the number of qubits and the parametric gates.  I am interested in both real quantum hardware and simulators.

In the case of simulators, I guess that it will grow exponentially with the number of qubits, but it is not clear to me how it will grow with parametric gates (and if it will take longer with certain gates).

I would appreciate any information you can give me or any paper you can recommend.

Thank you very much